# Can I access Wunderlist ToDo list in Java?

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, wunderlist

we need to implement a client Java application, which needs to retrieve ToDos list from Wunderlist using user name and password.

The main issue here for me is authentication against Wunderlist without any intervention from an end-user.
The developer documentation says that it is only possible to authenticate via web browser with user approval, etc.

The unofficial API from here http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2014/05/02/decodewunderlistapi2.html doesn't work for me, i.e. doesn't recognize my Wunderlist user name and password and always returns 404 error.

Any examples or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

the WL2 API was disabled some time ago :)

please send an email to api@wunderlist.com and we will see what we can do to help you.

Cheers
Hannes

(android dev @ 6wunderkinder.com)

Answer (score 0):

On developer.wunderlist.com you can register your application. You'll then receive a client id and token you can use to authenticate:

```
Developers must register their application before getting started.
Registration assigns a unique client ID and client secret 
for your application’s use. 
After you have registered your application, you can let Wunderlist
users authorize access to their account information from 
your application by getting an access token.
```

More info here: https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/concepts/authorization